# regex email validation

Tags: java, regex, count

this is a continuation of my earlier post, My code:

```
public class Main {

static String theFile = "C:\\Users\\Pc\\Desktop\\textfile.txt";

public static boolean validate(String input) {
    boolean status = false;
    String REGEX = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        status = true;
    } else {
        status = false;
    }
    return status;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(theFile));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] arr = line.split("#");
            for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
                if (arr[x].equals(validate(theFile))) {
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("no of matches " + count);

            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Main.validate(theFile);
}

}
```

It shows result :
no of matches 0
no of matches 0
no of matches 0
no of matches 0

and this is my text in input file 
sjbfbhbs@yahoo.com # fgfgfgf@yahoo.com # ghghgh@gamil.com #fhfbs@y.com

my output should be three emails because the last string is not a standard email format
I know I'm not suppose to pass `(arr[x].validate(theFile)))`

Comment: before writing an email validator, please have a look at these [examples of valid and invalid email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples)

Comment: http://emailregex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used this:

```
    public static bool Validate(string email)
    {
        string expressions = @"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$";
        return Regex.IsMatch(email, expressions);
    }
```

Note: I also have a function that "cleans" the string should there be multiple `@` symbols also.

Edit: Here is how I clean out extra `@` symbols. Note this will keep the FIRST `@` it finds and just remove the rest. This function should be used BEFORE you run the validation function on it.

```
    public static string CleanEmail(string input)
    {
        string output = "";

        try
        {
            if (input.Length > 0)
            {
                string first_pass = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w\.@-]", "");
                List<string> second_pass = new List<string>();
                string third_pass = first_pass;
                string final_pass = "";

                if (first_pass.Contains("@"))
                {
                    second_pass = first_pass.Split('@').ToList();

                    if (second_pass.Count >= 2)
                    {
                        string second_pass_0 = second_pass[0];
                        string second_pass_1 = second_pass[1];

                        third_pass = second_pass_0 + "@" + second_pass_1;

                        second_pass.Remove(second_pass_0);
                        second_pass.Remove(second_pass_1);
                    }
                }

                if (second_pass.Count > 0)
                {
                    final_pass = third_pass + string.Join("", second_pass.ToArray());
                }
                else
                {
                    final_pass = third_pass;
                }

                output = final_pass;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: What's the function?interesting

Comment: @valentine PM me.

Comment: how ? I'm new @David Bentley

Comment: have experience on mock mvc ? controller test spring boot

Comment: @valentine Nope. I write RDP software, database management software, windows services, and phone apps.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code:

1. `if (arr[x].equals(validate(theFile)))` checks whether the mail address string equals the boolean value you get from the `validate()` method. This will never be the case.
2. In the `validate()` method, if you only want to check if the string matches a regex, you can simply do that with `string.matches(pattern)` - so you only need one line of code (not really in error, but it's more elegant this way)
3. After splitting your input string (the line), there are whitespaces left, because you only split at the `#` symbol. You can either `trim()` each string afterwards to remove those (see the code below) or `split()` at `\\s*#\\s*` instead of just `#`

Here is an example with all the fixes (i left out the part where you read the file and used a string with your mail addresses instead!):

```
public class Main {

    private static final String PATTERN_MAIL
        = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    public static boolean validate(String input) {
        return input.matches(PATTERN_MAIL);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "sjbfbhbs@yahoo.com # fgfgfgf@yahoo.com # ghghgh@gamil.com #fhfbs@y.com";
        String[] arr = line.split("#");
        int count = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
            if (validate(arr[x].trim())) {
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("no of matches " + count);
        }
    }

}
```

It prints:

```
no of matches 1
no of matches 2
no of matches 3
no of matches 4
```

EDIT: If the pattern is not supposed to match the last mail address, you'll have to change the pattern. Right now it matches all of them.

Comment: if my answer solves your problem, you may mark it as accepted for others to use and for my worthless prestige points :)